# Drupal 7 has lost all "safe" values and summaries

Tags: nodes, entities, comments

I suddenly noticed that safe_value and safe_summary are empty now. Regular value is filled with data, but safe values are not. They were working just fine some time ago. I am currently trying hard to find what caused this havoc.

This applies to all nodes and comments. Haven't checked other content types yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was caused by Facebook album fetcher module and its text format filter.